# Can I know if the directory listing property is correctly setted on a FTP server?

Tags: ftp, directory-listing

I have to create a specific directory structure on an anonymous FTP server, these directories will contain some metadata files that will be read from a bot of a specific service...but this is not important now)

The important thing (these are basics requirements for the bot to be able to read the metadata files) are:

1) Directory listings must be enabled, the so-called -Lrat switch

2) Also, they should be configured to generate Unix style directory listings

I have no access to the FTP configuration and I have received the access from an IT but I am not sure that who gave me access has followed the previous configuration. Can I see it in some way? (looking at the server directory structure or in some other way)

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: If you're paying a hosting company to host your ftp? and they control the configurations? why don't you ask them?

Comment: Because the service is provided from the company for which I work but I am not sure that they have configured it in the right way...